# Laravel dynamic routes based on locale

Tags: php, laravel

So I have multiple slugs in my database, based on the locale. Now I want to display the correct route based on the locale as well, like so:

```
{{ route(__('categories.edit'), [$category->slug]) }}
```

But in my database, I have three slug fields, `slug_en`, `slug_es` and `slug_nl`.

The simple question is, how can I display the correct route based on the locale? I tried the following:

```
{{ route(__('categories.edit'), [$category->slug_ . app()->getLocale()]) }}
```

But this does not work, it displays only the locale in the slug, so the URL looks like below if the locale is set to `en`:

```
http://example.com/categories/en/edit
```

While it should be:

```
http://example.com/categories/correct-slug-here/edit
```

I do know this part of the route is wrong:

```
$category->slug_ . app()->getLocale()
```

But I do not know how to fix this properly after having searched for hours. I also know it should be a simple fix so hopefully someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the concatenation operator between two values here : `$category->slug_` and   `app()->getLocale()`.

The second value returns the locale and it is displayed in your route, however I assume your categories doesn't have a `slug_` attribute, that's not a string you are trying to concatenate what you should be doing is using the other syntax of getting an attribute :

```
 {{ route(__('categories.edit'), ['slug' => $category['slug_' . app()->getLocale()]]) }}
```

Comment: Thanks, tried this but getting the error "Array to string conversion"

Comment: @Hardist that's because the the second parameter of the route function should be an array including the parameters of the route, the syntax we were using was not right i didn't pay attention to that, I've edited my answer ( replace the slug key with the param name your route accepts )

Answer (score 1):

You need to add underscore in quotes and wrap column name in the square brackets, as it is a dynamic string.

```
{{ route(__('categories.edit'), [$category['slug_' . app()->getLocale()]]) }}
```

Or use curly brackets.

```
{{ route(__('categories.edit'), [$category->{'slug_' . app()->getLocale()}]) }}
```